# Why can we use a weaker metatheory for consistency results?

Tags: logic, set-theory

I'm not entirely sure why we can get away with using weaker metatheories for consistency results.

For instance consider the following, $ZFC \not \vdash Con(ZFC) \rightarrow Con(ZFC+I)$. This is because $ZFC + I \vdash Con(ZFC)$, and then if $ZFC \vdash Con(ZFC) \rightarrow Con(ZFC + I)$, we'd get $ZFC + I \vdash Con(ZFC + I)$, contradicting Godel's incompleteness theorem. So $ZFC$ *can't* be a metatheory for proving $Con(ZFC) \implies Con(ZFC + I)$. But $ZFC$ is far stronger than $PA$, so if it can't prove the consistency statement, why can $PA$? For instance, if $PA \vdash Con(ZFC) \implies Con(ZFC + I)$, then obviously $ZFC + I \vdash Con(PA)$, so why doesn't the same contradiction as above occur? Is it that $ZFC + I$ doesn't necessarily prove $Con(ZFC) \rightarrow Con(ZFC + I)$ even if $PA \vdash Con(ZFC) \rightarrow Con(ZFC+I)$? Then why did it work in the contradiction above? Was it because $ZFC \subseteq ZFC + I$?

This is just a specific example, but my question in general is: it seems that we can't prove consistency results in fairly strong theories, yet I often hear people say that $PA$ or even a finite fragment of $PA$ is enough for most consistency proofs.

Another example: using $ZFC + Con(ZFC) + \neg Con(ZFC + $"Inaccessibles exist"$)$ as our metatheory we definitely can't prove $Con(ZFC) \rightarrow Con(ZFC + $"inaccessibles exist"$)$. But the latter is a fairly easy consistency proof which we say that can be done in fairly weak metatheories. $ZFC + Con(ZFC) + \neg Con(ZFC + $"inacessibles exist"$)$ seems pretty strong to me.

Overall I'm interested in how the metatheory comes into play when describing consistency statements; it seems to me that the metatheory is very much important and yet people usually don't even mention what they're using.

Comment: I think there's some confusion here. In the second paragraph, we do **not** have $\mathsf{PA}\vdash Con(\mathsf{ZFC})\rightarrow Con(\mathsf{ZFC+I})$ unless $\mathsf{ZFC}$ itself is inconsistent, so there's no tension to be explained away. In the fourth paragraph the theory $\mathsf{ZF}+Con(\mathsf{ZF})+\neg Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$ is outright inconsistent, so the question there is moot.

Comment: Ok I replaced that example with another one which should hopefully be consistent. As to your first point, then I guess I must be mistaken: I often see people saying that to prove most consistency statements, we may work in a metatheory that is even weaker than $PA$. Does that not hold here? In which cases then can we use $PA$ as a metatheory, and what is the metatheory used to prove $Con(ZFC) \rightarrow Con(ZFC + I)$?

Comment: $Con(ZFC) \rightarrow Con(ZFC + I)$ is not generally considered to be a theorem, except to the extent that $Con(ZFC + I)$ itself is a theorem (for instance, if you accept stronger large cardinal axioms).

Comment: I see. So typically we take on faith $Con(ZF)$. We then are happy with using $ZFC$ thanks to the theorem $Con(ZF) \rightarrow Con(ZFC)$. Is there no such theorem for $ZFC + I$? That is, to believe in $Con(ZFC+I)$ we must build up our faith "from scratch" instead of believing something weaker, and using a consistency theorem? Are there any serious objections to $Con(ZFC + I)$?

Comment: @Moonish Yes, we cannot "reach $\mathsf{ZFC+I}$ from $\mathsf{ZF}$" - this is a consequence of Godel's second incompleteness theorem and the fact that $\mathsf{ZFC+I}\vdash Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$. As to whether there are any "serious objections," that's subjective but I'd tentatively say that there aren't, it's just a matter of degree.

Comment: @Moonish Yes. ZF and ZFC are the same consistency strength (and so is ZFC + CH and ZFC + $\lnot$CH for example), but ZFC + I is strictly higher consistency strength. Your first argument is actually a proof of this. I don't know if we're "happy" to add AC to ZF on these grounds... it does tell us it won't generate any new inconsistencies, and I suppose we're happy with that, but it doesn't mean AC is 'right'... for that, other philosophical arguments are required.

Comment: Got it. My question largely comes down to the incorrect impression that $Con(ZFC) \implies Con(ZFC + I)$ (which I guess I assumed because $Con(ZFC) \implies Con(ZFC + \neg I)$) I believe otherwise my doubts vanish.

Comment: So one more thing then: when people say "it is consistent with $ZF$ that every subset of the reals is measurable", they mean assuming an inaccessible, right? Since the Solovay model utilizes an inaccessible; so it's more like $Con(ZF+I) \implies Con(ZF+$"every subset of the reals is measurable"$)$. Unless there's a way to do it without inaccessibles of course.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question is based on an error, namely the claim that $Con(\mathsf{ZFC})\rightarrow Con(\mathsf{ZFC+I})$ is considered a theorem of the "standard metatheory" of mathematics. This is **not** the case. In particular, when people (correctly!) say that most relative consistency theorems can be proved in $\mathsf{PA}$ or even weaker systems, there's no tension here since $Con(\mathsf{ZFC})\rightarrow Con(\mathsf{ZFC+I})$ is not a relative consistency theorem in the sense meant.

Specifically, here's how I would phrase the heuristic claim above:

> In practice so far, whenever $T,S$ are "naturally occurring" theories containing $\mathsf{ZF}$ with $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash Con(T)\rightarrow Con(S)$, we have $\mathsf{PA}\vdash Con(T)\rightarrow Con(S)$.

(And in fact even less than $\mathsf{PA}$ is needed here; I'm not an expert here, but my understanding is that we can go down to $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$ without serious effort and even further if we take more care. [Hajek/Pudlak's book](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235421926) is a good resource here if you're interested.)

Note that the clause "containing $\mathsf{ZF}$" there is crucial, since if we go below $\mathsf{ZF}$ things trivialize: e.g. we boringly have $$\mathsf{ZF}\vdash Con(\emptyset)\rightarrow Con(\mathsf{PA})$$ since $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash Con(\mathsf{PA})$ outright, but of course $$\mathsf{PA}\not\vdash Con(\emptyset)\rightarrow Con(\mathsf{PA}).$$

The point then is that $T=\mathsf{ZFC}, S=\mathsf{ZFC+I}$ does **not** constitute a counterexample to this heuristic since - as you observe - we don't have $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash Con(\mathsf{ZFC})\rightarrow Con(\mathsf{ZFC+I})$ (unless $\mathsf{ZF}$ is inconsistent that is).

---

As to justifying stronger systems from below, Godel's second incompleteness theorem - as you observe in the OP - shows that we **cannot** reach $\mathsf{ZFC+I}$ from $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in the same way that we can reach $\mathsf{ZFC}$ from $\mathsf{ZF}$ (or $\mathsf{ZFC+GCH}$ from $\mathsf{ZF}$, or similar). The relevant term here is **consistency strength**: $\mathsf{ZFC+I}$ has strictly greater consistency strength than $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (unless the latter is inconsistent of course).

Comment: Yep, I was under the mistaken impression that $Con(ZFC) \rightarrow Con(ZFC+I)$. Without that I believe everything else clicks into place. So one more thing then: when people say "it is consistent with ZF that every subset of the reals is measurable", they mean assuming an inaccessible, right? Since the Solovay model utilizes an inaccessible; so it's more like Con(ZF+I)⟹Con(ZF+"every subset of the reals is measurable"). Unless there's a way to do it without inaccessibles of course. I won't lie, this is less cool since the existence of inaccessibles seems a stretch (to me at least).

Comment: @Moonish The accurate phrasing would be "If $\mathsf{ZFC+I}$ is consistent then so is $\mathsf{ZF+DC+}$ "All sets are measurable." Note $(i)$ the presence of the consistency assumption, but also $(ii)$ the role of $\mathsf{DC}$: without dependent choice, measure doesn't behave well enough for the question to be reasonable (e.g. without any additional hypotheses at all it turns out that if $\mathsf{ZF}$ is consistent then so is $\mathsf{ZF}$ + "$\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets," at which point every set is Borel and basic measure theory breaks down). So we keep $\mathsf{DC}$.

Comment: Both $(i)$ and $(ii)$ are frequently elided so we say "It's consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that all sets of reals are measurable." But granting $(ii)$ it turns out that $(i)$ is necessary: this was [proved by Shelah](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760522), and can be stated as $$\mathsf{PA}\vdash Con(\mathsf{ZFC+I})\leftrightarrow Con(\mathsf{ZF+DC+Meas})$$ (where I'm writing "$\mathsf{Meas}$"  for the statement "all sets of reals are measurable"). This followed Solovay's result which can be written as $$\mathsf{PA}\vdash Con(\mathsf{ZFC+I})\rightarrow Con(\mathsf{ZF+DC+Meas}).$$

Comment: That is, Solovay proved than an inaccessible is enough, and Shelah proved that it's neccessary. And all of this - while formulated over $\mathsf{ZFC}$ - is provable within $\mathsf{PA}$ by standard tedium. In case you're interested in digging into the details, Solovay's theorem is by far the easier of the two although it already requires a solid understanding of forcing (I'd read a modern presentation though, the exposition's been greatly improved over time); I don't think I've ever actually learned the whole of Shelah's argument, although I've picked at it a couple times.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. "It is consistent with ZF that all sets are measurable" sounds to me like $Con(ZF(C)) \implies Con(ZF + DC + Meas)$ so I suppose I made the wrong assumption. I think I do have the right understanding then, just mistakenly thinking $Con(ZFC) \rightarrow Con(ZFC + I)$ made me question everything xD. 




 One last question: Could you point me towards any discussion on why to believe $Con(ZFC +I)$? Or is it just that set theorists are interested in it because of its rich properties, and don't necessarily believe it's consistent either?

Comment: I found a few discussions actually so don't worry about it after all. Thank you once again for bearing with me!